# opening a java project in Bluej

Tags: java, bluej

I'm using eclipse to create a simple java project which contain 2 classes. After saving it in my workspace, i wanted to open them in Bluej. (my lecturer says that he checks our projects in bluej so we have to compile it also in bluej before sending him the .java files and check that everything is going well). I chose the "open a non-bluej project" option in the bluej menu, marked my project folder and pressed open. I recieved a warning massage, something about packages and after continue it, everything looked well but then i wanted to re-open the project in eclipse and it shows me an error sign in the classes which says that the package was changed. 
Please help me! I want to work with eclipse and only compile it with bluej when i finish, just to check that everything is ok. 
This is the Bluej warning massage:
[image]

Comment: Looks like your directory structure is wrong.  Make a copy of the project, open the copy with BlueJ, and hit continue.   It looks like it'll fix it for you.

Comment: after i hit continue,  i tried to re-open the project in eclipse and it shows me an error sign in the classes which says that the package was changed.

Comment: (sigh).  Your IDEs aren't helping you.  Forget the tools.  Fix your directory structures and package names using a text editor.  If they are correct, both IDEs will accept them.  Learn the language, not the IDE.